# Reading extension configuration from configuration file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Please help to read the configuration values from the configuration contribution point. In the `${extension_path}\package.json` I how following section:

```
{
    "name": "markdown-table-of-contents",
    "displayName": "Generate table of contents for markdown",
    "publisher": "dkultasev",
    "description": "",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.31.0"
    },
    "categories": [
        "Other"
    ],
    "activationEvents": [
        "onCommand:extension.sqlGenerateYAMLComment"
    ],
    "main": "./out/extension.js",
    "contributes": {
        "configuration": {
            "title": "Default name to use for YAML comment block",
            "properties": {
                "markdown-table-of-contents.author_name": {
                    "type": [
                        "string",
                        "Change Name"
                    ],
                    "default": null,
                    "description": "Specify default name when generating YAML comment block"
                }
            }


        }
...
```

then in the `extension_folder\.vscode\settings.json` I have setting `"markdown-table-of-contents.author_name": "Dmitrij Kultasev"` and in the extension code I'm trying to get these values:

```
const name = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('markdown-table-of-contents').get('author_name');
```

and it is `Change Name` but I expect `Dmitrij Kultasev` as configured in `settings.json` file

Comment: Are you sure? I get `null` when I `console.log()` it, not `undefined`, which is expected since that's the `"default"`. When I change the default to a string, it also reports that string as expected.

Comment: yeah, it[s null, sorry. Modified the question

Comment: Then I don't understand the question - surely `null` is the expected result, since that's the default value you specified?

Comment: how to configure this setting? How to put it to settings.json file and read it?

Comment: Yeah, but that part works for me as well. Of course it can't just be a random file named `settings.json`, it has to be either the global `settings.json` or a workspace `.vscode/settings.json`.

Comment: updated the question. I've set this setting in workspace settings file

Comment: `extension_folder\.vscode\settings.json`? You mean `workspace_folder\.vscode\settings.json`?

Comment: I understood. I set this setting in the workspace, however while debugging development host was open with another workspace. Thanks.